# Setting up peer Awareness for Spring Cloud Netflix based Eureka Server

Tags: configuration, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I build a Eureka server using Spring Cloud Netflix. The server is working so I am currently trying to add a second Eureka Server to improve resilience and provide a fallback server when updating the server.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html makes this sound pretty easy: You just have to config your server like Eureka clients themselves. So I added to my *bootstrap.yml* configuration for the client:

```
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://user:password@172.31.7.240:8762/eureka/
```

As far as I can tell this is identical to the config currently used by my other eureka clients. So I assumed this would work. But instead I get a strange exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryManagerIntitializer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.DiscoveryManagerInitializer.clientConfig; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaClientConfigBean': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=eureka.client, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'eureka.client' on field 'serviceUrl': rejected value [http://user:password@172.31.7.240:8762/eureka/]; codes [typeMismatch.eureka.client.serviceUrl,typeMismatch.serviceUrl,typeMismatch.java.util.Map,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [eureka.client.serviceUrl,serviceUrl]; arguments []; default message [serviceUrl]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'serviceUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map] for property 'serviceUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'eureka.client' on field 'serviceUrl': rejected value [http://user:password@172.31.7.240:8762/eureka/]; codes [typeMismatch.eureka.client.serviceUrl,typeMismatch.serviceUrl,typeMismatch.java.util.Map,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [eureka.client.serviceUrl,serviceUrl]; arguments []; default message [serviceUrl]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'serviceUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map] for property 'serviceUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.emnos.registry.RegistryApplication.main(RegistryApplication.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is clear that my URL is actually read from the configuration (at it appears in the exception). But it looks like it is parsed incorrectly. The exception tells me I am using a `String` for *eureka.client.serviceUrl* when I should use a `Map`. 
But I am in fact using a `Map` with the key-value pair `defaultZone: http://user:password@172.31.7.240:8762/eureka/`.

Has anybody seen a exception like this before and can tell me what I am doing wrong? As fat as I can tell I am using exactly the same syntax as is used in the Spring documentation.

**Edit:**

I just updated to Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Netflix 1.0.1.RELEASE so I should be using the latest version.

Comment: Whitespace error in the YAML?

Comment: Actually I don't think that error correlates with the YAML you  posted. Either the YAML is wrong or you have another property source with a bad value in it?

Comment: @DaveSyer thanks for your input. Whitespace in the YAML was among the first things I checked as this is a common problem. I just started the application locally and everything works. (I cannot explain why I did not try this yesterday...) So the problem is most likely with how it is deployed using Ansible. I am sorry. I was stupid. :D

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out after the comments form @DaveSyer.

There was in fact an other property source: Environment variables. A variable named `EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL`was defined unintentional overwriting the configuration from the YAML. After I removed/renames this variable everything started working.